# React Hooks are wierd

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

```
import './App.css';
import { MenuItem, FormControl, Select, Card, CardContent } from "@material-ui/core";

function App() {
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
  const [country, setCountry] =useState("WorldWide");

  useEffect(() => {
    const getCountriesData = async () => {
      await fetch("https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/countries").then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
        const countries = data.map(country => ({
          name: country.country,
          value: country.countryInfo.iso2
        }));
        setCountries(countries);
      });
    };
    getCountriesData();
  }, []);

  const onCountryChange = (event) => {
    const countryCode = event.target.value;
    setCountry(countryCode);
  }

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <div className="app__header">
        <h1>Covid-19 Tracker</h1>
        <FormControl className="app__dropdown">
          <Select
            variant="outlined"
            onChange={onCountryChange}
            value={country}
          >
            <MenuItem value="WorldWide">WorldWide</MenuItem>
            {countries.map(country => (<MenuItem value={country.value}>{country.name}</MenuItem>))}

          </Select>

        </FormControl>
      </div>
      {/* Title + Select input dropdown */}

      {/* InfoBoxes */}
      {/* InfoBoxes */}
      {/* InfoBoxes */}

      {/* Table */}
      {/* Graph */}
      {/* Map */}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In the above code I am using a state `country` which I am updating through `setCountry` depending on what the user chooses from the select dropdown options. I was following a tutorial but what I don't understand is in the function `onCountryChange()` when I do `setCountry(countryCode)` the name of the selected  country shows up. Every thing works but how? Since `countryCode` is set to `event.target.value` and the `value` is nothing but a two character code of the specific country. So how does the `setCountry` sets the `country` to the entire name of the country when what I am passing is just the country code which is just two letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set a Select option's `value` prop, it will select the matching option that has the same value.

The MenuItem value is set here:

```
<MenuItem value={country.value}>{country.name}</MenuItem>
```

The value, and the `country` state, do indeed take only the country abbreviation - but once the matching option is selected, the text content of the element is the `country.name`, which gives the full name of the country.

Comment: Yes, but the Select's value *determines* which menu item gets selected as a result - which determines which one gets displayed - which determines which country's `{country.name}` gets shown.